# I'm looking for a grammar/parser for elasticsearch query_string

Tags: search, search-engine

What I'm trying to achieve is to generate a valid elasticsearch [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) form inputs preferably in frontend.
In worst case it can be generated in the backend (nodeJS, NestJS).
I'm looking for libraries which can generate the query_string mentioned above and parse it back so I can add more criterias to the search without string concatenation i.e. `queryString += 'OR (big apple)'`.
I already found a [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pegjs/x4Zh_phvunk) which already proves that the query_string is forwarded to Lucene (inside of elasticsearch), so Lucene compatible query_string might be acceptable.